# Selenium WebDriver C# Actions are not performed, but nunit shows its okay

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a part of code: mouseover an element, then click on the subelement that have appeared:

```
`IWebElement menulink = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(""));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.MoveToElement(menulink).Build().Perform();
IWebElement sublink = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(""));
builder.MoveToElement(sublink).Click(sublink).Build().Perform();`
```

Nunit shows that test was run successully, but Chrome browser does not perform any actions.  What is the mistake?

Comment: You should post the relevant HTML in the question. From the code you have, you have blank CssSelectors... is that intentional? My guess is that the element exists, is hovered over, and clicked but it's not the element that you are looking for so it does nothing (visible).

Comment: BTW... you should add a validation after this code runs that demonstrates that the code ran successfully. Does the page navigate or something changes on the page or ??? Put that into a validation... that will cause the test to fail.